# Phpmyadmin can access from any login and password

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, phpmyadmin

I have recently purchased VPS and I installed LAMP on it. When I access *Phpmyadmin* through browser it asks login and password. Even if I insert wrong password I can login successfully. I even checked it in another PC with other network, I was allowed to login.

So, how can I make a change in such a way that wrong password and login combination don't allow user to log in.

Note: I have installed `fail2ban` and `iptables` in the server.
Checked in the `phpmyadmin` config file

```
/etc/panel/configs/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

but could not find

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Please look for another line like `if (!empty($dbname)) {
    // other configuration options
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
    // it should be placed before the following line
    $i++;
}`

Comment: @george that should probably be the answer, not a comment, straight away.

Comment: @george should I put $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = FALSE; before $i++; ??

Comment: Yes I believe that should be the case...